# Comments text entry bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

To reproduce:

- Start entering a comment with the iPhone in portrait
- Rotate to landscape
- Do a big scroll to existing comments and question until the keyboard is removed
- Rotate back to portrait

Now I'm treated to a blank form. The question and comments disappears.

Comment: Taking a look at this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for catching this – I was not handling a rotation layout calculation correctly for the case when the keyboard was hidden. This will be **fixed in the next app update, version 1.0.2**.

Comment: Sweet, good work. Do I accept now or when I've tested it?

Comment: After you've tested it is probably best.